# Поместить переменную из GET-запроса в поле password

Tags: https, get

У меня не получается поместить переменную из GET-запроса в поле `password`. Это система безопасности или я что-то не так делаю?
Вот Get-запрос:

> ```
> https://site.com/ServiceLoginEmail=1111111111&Passwd=11111111111111111&Submit=%CE%F2%EF%F0%E0%E2%E8%F2%FC
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Если в форме стоит

```
<input type="password" name="Passwd">
```

То ни чего не получится, потому что поля типа password не транслируются в GET-запрос!!! Да и в принципе это маразм передавать пароль GET'ом.

Comment: Вот! Об этом в скайпе ему и писал что если нет 

> value="<?=$_GET['Passwd']?>"

то не прокатит.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, во-первых, у вас ошибка.  Надо вот так:

```
https://site.com/ServiceLogin?Email=1111111111&Passwd=11111111111111111&Submit=%CE%F2%EF%F0%E0%E2%E8%F2%FC.
```

Во-вторых, передавать логин и пароль через URL крайне не разумно.

В-третьих, ответ на ваш вопрос:

```
$pass=$_GET['Passwd'];
```

Comment: Тут все дело в том, что код пишется для чужого сайта, на котором я не могу выполнить PHP...передавать переменные надо именно через URL. В моём случае их видеть никто не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на js:

```
var $_GET = {};
if(location.search.length){
    var _t = location.search.substr(1).split('&'), i = _t.length, kv = '';
    while(i--){
        kv = _t[i].split('=');
        $_GET[kv[0]] = kv[1];
    }
}
```

Так создается массив значений $_GET. А используя его, можно вставить значение в нужное поле.